# How to solve JavaFX runtime components are missing on VS code IDE

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javafx, fxml

I'm using JavaFx on visual studio code IDE. I always get this error:

> JavaFX runtime components are missing and are required to run this application

I've already added the VM args and the javafx libraries.

Also some basic FX codes are compiled with ease, but once I use the `FXMLLoader` class, I get the aforementioned error.

```java
package app;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class App extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) 
    {
        try 
        {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/interfaces/SignIn.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `launch.json`, adding a new entry for the `vmArgs` including the `--module-path` with the local path to the JavaFX SDK and `--add-modules` with the required JavaFX modules:

```
"vmArgs": "--module-path /path/to/javafx/lib  --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml"
```